# LinkedIn Mobile SDK exception: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn mobile SDK to deep link into the LinkedIn app and show my profile. After I have authenticated my app and gotten a valid session I use the deepLinkHelper class to open my profile.

The app crashes in the LinkedIn SDK method deepLinkToProfile on the line:
activity.startActivityForResult(i, LI_SDK_CROSSLINK_REQUEST_CODE);

The issue is LI_SDK_CROSSLINK_REQUEST_CODE is const set to 103287 which is larger than 64K. Since I can't change the SDK how to I work around this issue?

Thanks, Wray

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1.2 of the LinkedIn Android SDK has just been released and corrects this issue.